# Incorrect output with log object to xml

Tags: java, logging, jaxb, marshalling

I need to log XML message.
I use this code:

```
    //From object to xml
public String createMarshalerDealInfoType(DealInfoType dealInfoType) {
    StringWriter contactStr = null;
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DealInfoType.class);
        Marshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        contactStr = new StringWriter();
        jaxbUnmarshaller.marshal(dealInfoType, contactStr);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    return contactStr.toString();
}
```

In test class:

```
        ResponseType ResponseType = woNspDealWS.createRequestWS(DealRequestType);
        String DealResponce = updateDealEsb.createMarshalerDealInfoType(ResponseType.getDealInfo());
        log.debug("Response: \n " + DealResponce);
```

Problem: in log output I see only first line of responce, not whole message

```
    18:01:42,975 DEBUG updateDeal_Test:73 - Response:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

How do I make to print all response in XML?

SOLVED:
resolved problem with use annotation @XmlRootElement for test class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solving this problem need use annotation `@XmlRootElement` in test class

Answer (score 1):

The object which you have passed in test class might be empty 
ResponseType.getDealInfo()

Comment: I resolved problem with use annotation @XmlRootElement for test class.